# Combine two Oracle SQL queries with one LEFT OUTER JOIN and two INNER JOINS from four tables

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join, outer-join

I have two sql queries in Oracle that I would like to combine. The first query returns domain descriptions from a table and the second query will return only the domain descriptions that exist within the input parameter(COST_CENTER).

1st query:

```
SELECT distinct condition as condition_code, value as condition_literal
FROM CULVERT_INSPECT
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
   (SELECT EXTRACTVALUE (CodedValues.COLUMN_VALUE, 'CodedValue/Code')
              AS Code,
           EXTRACTVALUE (CodedValues.COLUMN_VALUE, 'CodedValue/Name')
              AS VALUE
      FROM GDB_ITEMS_VW items
           INNER JOIN GDB_ITEMTYPES itemtypes
              ON items.TYPE = itemtypes.UUID,
           TABLE (
              XMLSEQUENCE (
                 XMLType (Definition).EXTRACT (
                    '/GPCodedValueDomain2/CodedValues/CodedValue'))) 
 CodedValues
     WHERE itemtypes.Name = 'Coded Value Domain'
           AND items.Name = 'OVERALL_CONDITION') coded_values
             on CULVERT_INSPECT.condition = coded_values.code
 ORDER BY CONDITION_CODE
```

2nd Query:

```
SELECT distinct CULVERT_INSPECT.CONDITION
FROM CULVERTS
   INNER JOIN CULVERT_INSPECT ON (CULVERTS.GLOBALID_1 = 
CULVERTGID)
WHERE COST_CENTER = '551807'
```

The output from first query:

```
CONDITION_CODE  CONDITION_LITERAL
0               Excellent - Like New
1               Good - Some Wear, Structurally Sound
2               Poor - Deteriorated, Consider For Repair
3               Very Poor - Serious Deterioration
4               Inaccessible
```

Comment: `CULVERTGID` is a column from `CULVERT_INSPECT` -  is it unique in `CULVERT_INSPECT` for   a given `CONDITION`?

Comment: @KaushikNayak Yes, `CULVERTGID` is a column from `CULVERT_INSPECT`. It is a unique ID but not for a given `CONDITION`.

Comment: And Just to confirm, if you include `CULVERTGID`  in select of  your first query , you get the same number of rows?

Comment: @KaushikNayak Not necessarily. Sometimes a `COST_CENTER` will not have all `CONDITION_CODES`. We could try that though. `CULVERTGID` is used to match up related values from `GLOBALID_1` in `CULVERTS`.

Comment: `COST_CENTER`  is a column in `CULVERT_INSPECT` ?

Comment: @KaushikNayak No, it's a column in `CULVERTS`.

Comment: Ok. Then just try the query and let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this using a `with clause`. It is untested though as there is no sample data.

```
WITH cons
         AS (SELECT DISTINCT culvertgid , condition AS condition_code,
                             value     AS condition_literal
             FROM   culvert_inspect
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Extractvalue (CodedValues.column_value,
                                            'CodedValue/Code') AS Code,
                                            Extractvalue (CodedValues.column_value,
                                            'CodedValue/Name') AS VALUE
                                     FROM   gdb_items_vw items
                                            inner join gdb_itemtypes itemtypes
                                                    ON items.TYPE = itemtypes.uuid,
                                            TABLE (
            Xmlsequence (Xmltype (DEFINITION).EXTRACT (
                         '/GPCodedValueDomain2/CodedValues/CodedValue')))
                            CodedValues
                     WHERE  itemtypes.name = 'Coded Value Domain'
                            AND items.name = 'OVERALL_CONDITION')
                    coded_values
                 ON culvert_inspect.condition = coded_values.code)
    SELECT DISTINCT ci.condition_code
    FROM   culverts c
           INNER JOIN  cons ci
                   ON ( c.globalid_1 = ci.culvertgid )
    WHERE  cost_center = '551807'
    ORDER  BY condition_code;
```

Comment: It comes back with ORA-00904: "CI"."CULVERTGID": invalid identifier

Comment: check now . it was not added in the with clause